# Is there any way to resample in order to change the distribution of a sample?

Tags: distributions, sample, resampling

I ran an experiment that involved an independent variable which is known to have a right skewed distribution. However, in the experiment, the independent variable was distributed differently between manipulation and control, which means that the randomization didn't work as we want. Manipulation's variable was right-skewed but the control had an normal distribution. Is there anyway to resample my control to have a right-skewed distribution? Is there any method that takes a random subsample that is right-skewed from my normally distributed control over and over and over and ov… until we see which subsample is optimal to use?

Comment: "the randomization didn't work as we want" what do you want? I do not think the resampling can resolve your problem/

Comment: Something is different with how the control was chosen. How  is that?

Comment: If something went wrong in the randomization, it's hard to see how resampling is going to fix it.  But is there any real problem with a difference in distribution of an explanatory variable between the treatment and control groups?  Could you explain why you are focused on this aspect?